# 'WizardStep2Form' has no field named 'language_code'. in Djangocms aldryn_newsblog

Tags: django, django-cms

I have successfully installed aldryn_newsblog. am using djangocms.
 Every time i try to Create a new news/blog article. i get an error

```
    ValueError at /cms_wizard/create/
'WizardStep2Form' has no field named 'language_code'.
```

Here is my settings.py file INSTALLED_APPS

```
    #  Aldryn News & Blog
'aldryn_apphooks_config',
'aldryn_boilerplates',
'aldryn_categories',
'aldryn_common',
'aldryn_newsblog',
'aldryn_people',
'aldryn_reversion',
'aldryn_translation_tools',
#'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
#'easy_thumbnails',
#'filer',
'parler',
#'reversion',
'sortedm2m',
'taggit',
'absolute',
'aldryn_forms',
'aldryn_forms.contrib.email_notifications',
'captcha',
'emailit',
#  Aldryn News & Blog
```

Here is the full traceback

```
Traceback:
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in inner
  145.                     return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cms/wizards/views.py" in dispatch
  38.             request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/formtools/wizard/views.py" in dispatch
  237.         response = super(WizardView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/formtools/wizard/views.py" in post
  290.         if form.is_valid():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  184.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  176.             self.full_clean()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  394.         self._post_clean()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/parler/forms.py" in _post_clean
  83.         self.save_translated_fields()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/parler/forms.py" in save_translated_fields
  110.             self._clean_translation_model(translation_model, exclude)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/parler/forms.py" in _clean_translation_model
  125.                 self._update_errors(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py" in _update_errors
  402.         self.add_error(None, errors)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in add_error
  360.                         "'%s' has no field named '%s'." % (self.**class**.**name**, field))

Exception Type: ValueError at /cms_wizard/create/
Exception Value: 'WizardStep2Form' has no field named 'language_code'.

Kindly assist

Comment: Hello, can you post the full traceback?

Comment: Hello @Paulo i have edited the question to include the full traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just encountered a similar issue:
`'ArticleForm' has no field named 'language_code'.`

Turned out to be a conflict with the most recent version of `django-parler` ([see the changelog here](https://django-parler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html)).

> Note: django-parler models now mandate that a language code is selected; either by calling model.set_current_language(), Model.objects.language() or activating a gettext environment. The latter always happens in a standard web request, but needs to happen explicitly in management commands. This avoids hard to debug situations where unwanted model changes happen on implicitly selected languages.

For a quick fix, try running `pip uninstall django-parler` and then `pip install django-parler==1.6.2` (or pin the version in your `requirements.txt` file if you have one).

If you are able to update your versions of django, django CMS, and other dependencies, that may work as well (and not limit you to an older version of `django-parler`)

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thanks @andrewjadams3